# Set the number of rows dynamically for multiline text box

Tags: asp.net

I am entering some random text with space and in a text box during insert mode. Now in view mode I want to see those text as it was entered. For that I am using multiline text box and setting its border=none as he text should look like as it is label. I dont want to see any scroll bars. So I set column property=50 and assigning rows dynamically but still its not working. 
Here is the comments that I have inserted
"Testing commentsghgjhgvhgvhgvkhbvfjsghksjnlksnvs;vmns;lkfgnskljgklk            lkj;lkjlkjlk lkj'lkj

sdfgsg

dfg"

The code is as below

```
txtComments.Rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)dtSky.Rows[0]["Comments"].ToString().Length / 50);

txtComments.Text = dtSky.Rows[0]["Comments"].ToString();
```

How can I do this? I can use lable as per requirements....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say I want to see the text as it was entered.. as a label.  For this you shouldn't use a textbox with no border but a html element more suited to displaying text.  Either a div or a span or just a plain p.

To render a div in asp.net you could use an asp:literal with some html wrapping it

```
<div>
    <asp:Literal ID="commentsLiteral" runat="Server"></asp:Literal> 
<div>
```

in your code behind

```
commentsLiteral.Text = dtSky.Rows[0]["Comments"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps